# how to save settings in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How to save the settings that my app uses ?

should I use sql, xml , access or any other flexible & easy way.

Please provide a sample code to do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=131671

Comment: I think it was made on 2003 , do you think it still works for VS-2010 ?

Comment: I think the code uses XML, so do I need to install any additional files ? Like XML software or anything ?

Comment: Yes, because the system namespaces have not been moved and .net 1.1 coding styles are still supported

Comment: It should work out of the box and create you an xml file in documents and settings\{username}\application data

Comment: `_configFileType = ConfigFileType` What is the need of that underscore in the program , does that specify something ?

Comment: it's just an old way of specifying local or class level private scope

Comment: Thanks a lot :), that was a quick response :D

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I try to help :)

Comment: That article is 7 years old. It's much easier to use My.Settings, which has been built into VB.Net since 2005

Comment: It's not easier. It just makes a few bits less transparent. Somehow 5 years is prefered to 7 years? There is no shelf-life to code that works.

Comment: *Not easier*? Matter of opinion maybe, abcd... says its "the easiest thing ever." No downloaded class to paste into your project, it supports *many* more data types than just strings, Intellisense support for your setting names... Join us, it's great!

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft provide a built-in way to do this called My.Settings. Just use it, it's really easy. It uses XML behind the scenes, but you don't even need to know that - it does it all for you.

[Tutorial with sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Easiest thing ever, Thanks a lot +1